# Optimal base for continued fraction factorization

Tags: number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization, continued-fractions

I read somewhere that the optimal base for the continued fraction factorization algorithm is the set of primes less than or equal to $\lfloor exp(\frac{\sqrt{ln(N)ln(ln(n))}}{2})\rfloor$. I was wondering if anyone knew of a proof for this fact, as I couldn't find one.